# Convert HTML Into Image and Upload to Server

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using jQuery to convert HTML into image. Code as below:

```
var targetdocument = $("#container");
html2canvas(targetdocument, {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
        getCanvas = canvas;
        var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png;base64');
        $("#newimg").attr('src', imgData);
    },
});
```

and the final output of the image is base64 (not sure what is this) and it is super long. And now I would like to upload to server so that I can save the path with proper image name into database.

How to upload to server? How to change the image name into whatever I want? How to save into database?

Backend architecture is built by ASP.NET MVC5.

Comment: ordinarily you would generate a name for the uploaded file, move the file to the correct directory and then store the path in the database. But since you are already storing it as a base64 data set so you can directly store it ans output it.

Also Base 64 is essentially the image represented as a string that a browser can directly render

Comment: my question is: how to store the file into server?I can't store the base64 as image name in database as it's too long.

Comment: of course you can store it in the server just change the database column type to string. If you don't want to do that then you will need to create a blank file and then write the base64 data to it , then move the file to the proper directory and store the path in the database column. [This link](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Save-Base64-string-as-Image-File-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx) should help you (Im not a expert in asp so all i can do is provide references)

Comment: Uploading to server isn't that different if you are using `base64` just post  it to controller as model field string. but where exactly you are having a problem show your code what u have done so far?

Comment: @Alex are you actually suggesting that I should use base64 format to store the image?

Comment: if ur asking my suggestion then I dont think so